# Logstash 2.4.0 is not creating Elasticsearch 2.4.0 index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Logstash version 2.4.0, Elasticsearch version 2.4.0.

logstash.conf:

```
input {
  log4j2 {
    port => 7000
    mode => "server"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        }
}
```

logstash logs with --debug:

```
Reading config file {:config_file=>"/opt/logstash/conf/logstash.conf", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/loader.rb", :line=>"69", :method=>"local_config"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"input", :name=>"log4j2", :path=>"logstash/inputs/log4j2", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"86", :method=>"lookup"}
log4j2 plugin is using the 'milestone' method to declare the version of the plugin this method is deprecated in favor of declaring the version inside the gemspec. {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"208", :method=>"milestone"}
log4j2 plugin doesn't have a version. This plugin isn't well
 supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:warn, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"306", :method=>"print_version_notice"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"codec", :name=>"plain", :path=>"logstash/codecs/plain", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"86", :method=>"lookup"}
config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::Log4j2/@port = 7000 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::Log4j2/@mode = "server" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::Log4j2/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::Log4j2/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::Log4j2/@host = "0.0.0.0" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::Log4j2/@data_timeout = 5 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"output", :name=>"elasticsearch", :path=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"86", :method=>"lookup"}
starting agent {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"213", :method=>"execute"}
starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"487", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
Starting Log4j2 input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:7000", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/inputs/log4j2.rb", :line=>"60", :method=>"register"}
Log4j input {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/inputs/log4j2.rb", :line=>"63", :method=>"register"}
config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@hosts = ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@workers = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@index = "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@manage_template = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@template_name = "logstash" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@template_overwrite = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@parent = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@flush_size = 500 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@idle_flush_time = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@upsert = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@doc_as_upsert = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@max_retries = 3 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script_type = "inline" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script_lang = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script_var_name = "event" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@scripted_upsert = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@retry_max_interval = 2 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@retry_max_items = 500 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@retry_on_conflict = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@pipeline = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@action = "index" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@ssl_certificate_verification = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@sniffing = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@sniffing_delay = 5 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
Normalizing http path {:path=>nil, :normalized=>nil, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client_builder.rb", :line=>"18", :method=>"build"}
Elasticsearch HTTP client options {:hosts=>["http://127.0.0.1:9200"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb", :line=>"127", :method=>"build_client"}
Using mapping template from {:path=>nil, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb", :line=>"6", :method=>"install_template"}
Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "omit_norms"=>true}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true, "fielddata"=>{"format"=>"disabled"}}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true, "fielddata"=>{"format"=>"disabled"}, "fields"=>{"raw"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"float"}}}}}}}, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb", :line=>"8", :method=>"install_template"}
Found existing Elasticsearch template. Skipping template management {:name=>"logstash", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb", :line=>"30", :method=>"template_install"}
New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://127.0.0.1:9200"], :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb", :line=>"19", :method=>"register"}
Will start workers for output {:worker_count=>1, :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/output_delegator.rb", :line=>"77", :method=>"register"}
Starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :pipeline_workers=>2, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>250, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"188", :method=>"start_workers"}
Pipeline main started {:file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"491", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x22d1230d @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x50543c56>, @last_flush=2016-12-02 17:11:01 +0800, @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x2162cdef run>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x5dbe1708>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x1e302662@/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @flush_interval=1, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0x6b27fb69 @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0xdeae175>, @data={}, @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x3777cf76 @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0x6b27fb69 ...>, @metrics={}, @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x1ad5686d>>, @subscribers={13206=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x3b3596d0 @options={}, @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x7b47e585 @lock=#<Mutex:0x2d2dbdfe>, @io=#<IO:fd 1>>>}, @level=:debug>, @buffer=[], @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x161485de>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x22d1230d @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x50543c56>, @last_flush=2016-12-02 17:11:02 +0800, @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x2162cdef run>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x5dbe1708>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x1e302662@/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @flush_interval=1, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0x6b27fb69 @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0xdeae175>, @data={}, @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x3777cf76 @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0x6b27fb69 ...>, @metrics={}, @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x1ad5686d>>, @subscribers={13206=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x3b3596d0 @options={}, @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x7b47e585 @lock=#<Mutex:0x2d2dbdfe>, @io=#<IO:fd 1>>>}, @level=:debug>, @buffer=[], @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x161485de>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x22d1230d @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x50543c56>, @last_flush=2016-12-02 17:11:03 +0800, @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x2162cdef run>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x5dbe1708>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x1e302662@/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @flush_interval=1, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0x6b27fb69 @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0xdeae175>, @data={}, @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x3777cf76 @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0x6b27fb69 ...>, @metrics={}, @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x1ad5686d>>, @subscribers={13206=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x3b3596d0 @options={}, @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x7b47e585 @lock=#<Mutex:0x2d2dbdfe>, @io=#<IO:fd 1>>>}, @level=:debug>, @buffer=[], @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x161485de>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
```

The logstash log looks ok and it seems it is connected to elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is started in debug mode but the log shows nothing about logstash.

status of elasticsearch looks normal:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?v'

{"cluster_name":"logstash","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":0,"active_shards":0,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}
```

Comment: what is the health status of your elasticsearch cluster? Have you tried sending data to logstash yet?

Comment: elasticsearch status is green, output updated in question, thx